# Section-Iterate shows only 20 results?

Tags: moqui

Thanks a lot for your continuous support
I am using section iterate to generate a list to the data but when I display that list on UI only 20 results are displayed not all the results are displayed. I want that all the results should come as pagination does not work on section iterate so could you suggest ways to display the whole list using section-iterate ?

Comment: What does your data preparation look like for the list your section-iterate is iterating over (i.e. entity find, service call, etc)? Chances are the limit is there, but you can check by just throwing a label on the screen with the list size.

Comment: I am using entity-find for iteration purpose but the list when displayed on the screen shows only 20 records on a page not more then that and as pagination is not supported in section-iterate further data cannot be viewed.

Comment: That didn't answer my question... did you check to see if your entity-find results are limited to 20, or if the EntityList returned has more and the display is limited to 20?